# Pandas column-wise rolling works with np.float64 but returns empty array with np.float32 and np.float16

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I ran into a strange observation where the same code works with `np.float64` but not with `np.float32` or `np.float16`. Here's code to reproduce the results:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> print(pd.DataFrame(a, dtype=np.float64).rolling(3, axis=1).mean())

    0   1    2
0 NaN NaN  2.0

>>> print(pd.DataFrame(a, dtype=np.float32).rolling(3, axis=1).mean())

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0]
```

`np.float16` produces the same result.

This happens on numpy 1.20.3 and pandas 1.2.4. I experimented with numpy 1.20.0 and it worked fine.

I managed to remove errors in my code by explicitly setting the datatype as `np.float64`, but couldn't figure out why this happens.

Does anyone has any ideas about the root of the problem? And does the problem come from numpy or pandas?

Comment: I think this is topic for some pandas github issue. From there it may travel to numpy