# Python Rolling sum for 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, rolling-computation

I am getting strange results when doing **rollingSum** for 64 bit vs 32 bit precision. Please see the code for display 1 vs 2. **Display 1** shows the right rolling sum but **Display 2** shows empty result dataframe. I am using python 3.9 FYI

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
dfa = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
dfa=dfa.astype('float64')
dfb=dfa.astype('float32')
display(dfa.rolling(2, axis="columns").sum())
display(dfb.rolling(2, axis="columns").sum())

Results:
Display1: 
    A   B   C   D
0   NaN 20.0    20.0    38.0
1   NaN 35.0    31.0    34.0
2   NaN 15.0    14.0    16.0
3   NaN 13.0    29.0    34.0
4   NaN 19.0    25.0    23.0

Display2:
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69980657/pandas-column-wise-rolling-works-with-np-float64-but-returns-empty-array-with-np

Comment: this seems to be fixed on the master branch

Comment: `dfb.T.rolling(2, axis=0).sum()` works

Comment: is this a numpy issue or Panda's issue?

Comment: Pandas issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42452

Comment: could not reproduce `sys.version -> 3.8.3`, `pd.__version__ -> 1.1.3 `

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved in Pandas version 1.4.0

[BUG: dataframe.rolling along rows drops float16](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/42884)

[BUG: DataFrame.rolling(axis=1) operations drop/ignore float16 and float32 columns](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41779)